# array.filter() and array.some() not acting as expected with an '||' condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

Here is a working example (and [here](https://repl.it/repls/LeanLostElectricity#index.js) is a link to something you can play with):

```
  var idDateArray = [
  {
    id: '1',
    updateTime: '00:00:00.000Z',
    updateDate: '2019-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    updateTime: '00:00:00.000Z',
    updateDate: '2021-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    updateTime: '00:00:00.000Z',
    updateDate: '2019-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    updateTime: '00:00:00.000Z',
    updateDate: '2019-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    updateTime: '00:00:00.000Z',
    updateDate: '2020-01-01'
  }
]

var itemArray = [
      {
        updateDate: '2020-01-01',
        updateTime: '00:00:00.000Z',
        id: '4'
      },
      {
        updateDate: '2020-01-02',
        updateTime: '00:00:00.000Z',
        id: '2'
      },
      {
        updateDate: '2021-01-02',
        updateTime: '00:00:00.000Z',
        id: '3'
      },
      {
        updateDate: '2020-01-01',
        updateTime: '00:00:00.000Z',
        id: '1'
      }
    ]
 
 var filteredArray = idDateArray.filter((row) =>
        itemArray.some(
            (item) =>
              //item.id !== row.id || // <-LINE IN QUESTION
                (item.id === row.id &&
                    Date.parse(row.updateDate + 'T' + row.updateTime) >
                        Date.parse(item.updateDate + 'T' + item.updateTime)),
        ),
    );

    console.log(filteredArray);
```

What I am not understanding is why this `||` condition won't work as I expect?  In the above example, when the LINE IN QUESTION is removed, all objects in `idDateArray` whose `id` matches those in `itemArray` AND date/time is `>` those in `itemArray` should be removed.  And they are (id 2 is all that is left).

I then add in the or condition, which I would then expect to not only filter on matched id's and greater than date time, but also filter those that dont have any match on id.  I.E. If either condition is true, remove from `idDateArray`.

Comment: The line in question is commented out

Comment: I know.  If you uncomment it, neither condition is run.  All 5 objects are returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, you're saying "keep it if there is *any* item in the array where `item.id !== row.id`", and there's presumably always going to be at least a single item where the id doesn't match, you're using `.some` not `.every`